# AJAX New XMLHttpRequest at Interval not firing more than once

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using ajax and php to create a timer and check a queue. This works well however once the timer is expired I need to check the queue again. The onExpiry call works but I am not getting the new timer value. I can only get a new timer if I reload the page. Does the XMLHttpRequest need to be cleared in order to call it again?

```
<script>
function checkQB(x) {
if (x==1) {
  xmlhttp.abort();
  }
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET','inc/php/QBconn.php',true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    var dt=xmlhttp.responseText;
    if ((/^20/).test(dt)==1) {
      var split = dt.split(',');
      var newYear = new Date();
      newYear = new Date(split[0], split[1]-1, split[2], split[3], split[4], 00);
      $('#QBconn').countdown({
        until: newYear, onExpiry: liftOff, layout: 'Next Run in {mn} {ml}, {sn} {sl}'
      });
      }
    else {
      document.getElementById('QBconn').innerHTML='Error';
      }
    }
  }
}

function liftOff() {
  checkQB(1);
  }

checkQB();
</script>

<div id="QBconn"></div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Countdown needed to be destroyed
xmlhttprequest was functioning normally

```
if (x==1) {
  xmlhttp.abort();
  $('#QBconn').countdown('destroy');
  }
```